# How to write an sql query that takes input(multiple) from one query and then uses the values to search and column and exchange where ever not found?

Tags: sql

For example, input will be as follows:

| ID |
| --- |
| 101 |
| 102 |
| 103 |
| 104 |

This will be searched in below type of data:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 202 |
| 101 | 204 |
| 202 | 101 |
| 203 | 101 |

Output should be:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 202 |
| 101 | 204 |
| 101 | 202 |
| 101 | 203 |

For each entry that encounters this situation,

Can we do this without cursors & procedures?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

You may left join your source table to the table of inputs, then use `CASE` logic to decide whether or not to swap the values.

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t1.ID1 ELSE t1.ID2 END AS ID1,
    CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NOT NULL THEN t1.ID2 ELSE t1.ID1 END AS ID2
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN input t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner join` to join inputs with your table and then use `group by` to get rid of duplicates, and `CASE` clause to pick the correct data

```
with inputs as (
    select 101 as id union all
    select 101 as id union all
    select 101 as id union all
    select 101 as id
)
select id AS ID1, case when ID1 <> id then ID1 else ID2 END AS ID2
from mytable t
inner join inputs i on i.id = t.ID1 or i.id = t.ID2
group by ID1, ID2, id
```

[Check the demo on mysql](https://dbfiddle.uk/aFehPT_3)

Answer (score 0):

A simple union will do it.

```
CREATE TABLE ids
    (id1 int, id2 int)
;
    
INSERT INTO ids
    (id1, id2)
VALUES
    (101, 202),
    (101, 204),
    (202, 101),
    (203, 101),
    (102, 202),
    (105, 204),
    (202, 102),
    (203, 105)
;

select id1, id2 from ids where id1 in (101,102,103,104) 
union
select id2 as id1, id1 as id2 from ids where id2 in (101,102,103,104)
```

Results

```
id1 id2
101 202
102 202
101 203
101 204
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4e51/3/0)

[Here is a version that sorts the results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4e51/8/0).

Since no SQL engine was tagged I used Postgres for the examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with a simple join.

```
WITH InputData AS (SELECT ID FROM input_table)

SELECT DISTINCT
    i.ID AS ID1,
    CASE
        WHEN i.ID = t.ID1 THEN t.ID2
        ELSE t.ID1
    END AS ID2 
FROM InputData i 
JOIN your_table t ON i.ID = t.ID1 OR i.ID = t.ID2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another union version with an input table.

```
CREATE TABLE ids
    (id1 int, id2 int)
;

CREATE TABLE input (
      id1 int
);
   
INSERT INTO INPUT
(id1)
VALUES
(101),
(102),
(103),
(104);

INSERT INTO ids
    (id1, id2)
VALUES
    (101, 202),
    (101, 204),
    (202, 101),
    (203, 101),
    (102, 202),
    (105, 204),
    (202, 102),
    (203, 105)
;
```

and the SQL

```
SELECT results.id1, results.id2
FROM input INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id1, id2 FROM ids 
    UNION
    SELECT id2 as id1, id1 as id2 FROM ids
) AS results
ON input.id1 = results.id1
ORDER BY results.id1, results.id2
```

with the results

```
id1 id2
101 202
101 203
101 204
102 202
```

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91dcad/2